# Need to implement a scrolling list with selected item visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, mean-stack

The requirement is a scroll-able list of items with a certain item highlighted, and visible by default. So, if item 50 in a list of 100 is the special selected item, the list would be initially displayed by scrolling down enough so item 50 is in the middle of the list.

This is a MEAN stack application, and I already have the items loaded from a service and populating a template using *ngFor, but the visual requirement of highlighting a specific item *and making that item visible by default* is not working well.

The additional requirement (isn't management great?) is that each item should be multi-line and html formatted info, so an html select filled every need except that one.

I'm currently using an un-ordered list with css overflow to handle the scrolling, but that doesn't give me the ability to scroll down to a specific item.

```
<nav>
  <ol style="height:500px; width:100%; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;">
    <li *ngFor="let item of list">
      <table>
        <tr *ngIf="item.store_number == my_store; else otherstore"><b>{{item.store_number}}</b></tr>
        <ng-template #otherstore><tr>{{item.store_number}}</tr></ng-template>
        <div style="color:gray">
          <small>
            <tr>{{item.detail[0].address.store_address.line1}}
              {{item.detail[0].address.store_address.line2}}</tr>
            <tr>{{item.detail[0].address.store_address.city}},
              {{item.detail[0].address.shop_store_address.state}}</tr>
          </small>
        </div>
      </table>
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Any ideas on how to implement this? One last requirement: must be html/css/javascript/typescript. No purpose-built npm packages, because management.

- Scrolling list
- Multi-line items
- ...with ability to format items using html/css
- Ability to scroll down to a specific item

Comment: Calculate the height of your scrollable div(since you've already set it that shouldnt be a problem) and then the position of the element within that div. And then using the `scrollTo()`with the position as the parameter. That's how I would probably do it. With that logic you could Google how to get said variables. Would have give  you a sample cos if I was home right now , but I hope that helps a bit. Good luck.

Comment: Also remove the `overflow:hidden` property since you're already setting scroll to y